# Issues with a static variable in C

Tags: c

say I have 4 files.

```
file1.h
file1.c
file2.h
file2.c
```

in `file1.h`  I have a variable :

```
static short mode=0;
```

in `file1.c`:

```
#include "file1.h"
...............
if ( mode ==0)
  do stuff
else {
   do something else 
}
```

the problem I have is that I can only change `mode` value in `file2.c`

in file2.h I include file1.h   and in the source file2.c, I change the value of to `1` but this has no influence on it in `file1.c`

Comment: I think it might need to be declared 'extern', and defined in one of the c files...not sure though.

Comment: "*in file2.h I include file1.h*" You should not do that, if your includes are not protected enough from multiple inclusion (with `#ifdef`s and such) it can lead to quite a few problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a line like

```
static short mode=0;
```

in a .h file and the .h file is included in multiple .c files, you effectively create multiple `short mode` variables, one in each .c file that ends up including the .h file.

If you want to have one variable, make it `extern`, make sure to define it in only one .c file.

in file1.h:

```
// Just the declaration in the .h file.
extern short mode;
```

in file1.c:

```
// The definition in only one .c file.
short mode = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of having a variable declared as `static` is to reduce its scope and make it inaccessible to other files. This is known as *private encapsulation* and is *good programming practice*.

The opposite of private encapsulation is known as *spaghetti coding*, where you declare a variable as global, with the `extern` keyword. This is *very bad programming practice* (unless in some cases where the variable is declared const, which isn't the case here).

**Under no circumstances should you attempt to rewrite good code based on private encapsulation into bad code based on spaghetti.**

Also you should never *define* variables in header files, because that never makes any sense. A header file is just a description of the interface which is implemented in its corresponding c file, it should not implement anything (even though C allows one to do all kinds of stupid and crazy things).

What you should do is:

file1.h

```
short get_mode (void);
void  set_mode (short m);
```

file1.c

```
#include "file1.h"

static short mode = 0;

short get_mode (void)
{
  return mode;
}

void set_mode (short m)
{
  mode = m;
}
```

some_other_file.c

```
#include "file1.h"

short mode = get_mode();
do_stuff_with(mode);
```

This is how you design programs properly, period. No matter which programming language that is used. Do not listen to anyone recommending `extern` or other such nonsense!

Comment: Mandatory comment from some 1980s dinosaur that will follow: "But this adds several CPU ticks of overhead code." Mandatory answer will follow: "No, all compilers on the market are perfectly capable of inlining code, and have been so since the mid 90s".

Comment: Nice. Hats off to you :)

Comment: Hang on. You complain that global variables are bad programming practice, but you still have one! It's just that you've hidden it. All the normal global variable problems, such as lack of reentrancy and lack of thread safety, still apply.

Comment: @JackWhitham Global variables are variables that are accessible globally everywhere in the project, hence global. This example has a _local file scope variable_ which is not the same thing. The main problems with globals are avoided: spaghetti program design and cluttering of the global namespace. But indeed any static variable will become problematic in multi-threaded systems and therefore needs to be protected by semaphores.

Comment: I second @JackWhitham. Blindly programming getters and setters is not (much) better than plain access to a global variable. In particular it does not solve the potential complexity introduced by global access to properties. (The caveat is that it responds better to implementation changes.)

Comment: The arguments you give are not valid, imo: "spaghetti program design" is not prevented at all (if assignments are replaced by get or set, how does that improve program structure?); and "cluttering of the global namespace" is, if anything, increased because the getter and setter introduce *two* names instead of just one, the variable name.

Comment: I would also argue that this is not an answer; the question is about a basic facility of the C programming language and not about language independent program design.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Variables (and macros) in the global namespace are far more dangerous than functions, because of the potential for accidental use by mistake in large code bases. As for how avoiding globals lead to better program design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29. Or go maintain any program larger than 10k LOC that uses global variables and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: I do not see how global setters and getter backed by a file static variable (i.e. your proposal) are better maintainable or less likely to be used accidentally than a simple global variable (the OP's attempt).  In both cases a global state is globally accessible, which can be a maintenance problem. And in both cases a decent programming environment, GUI or not, spits out all uses in no time. The wikipedia article, by contrast, mentions poor man's OOP through opaque structures with factory and manipulator functions operating on them, which improves encapsulation but plays in a different league.

Comment: @PeterSchneider The difference is in the design: the implementation is hidden to the caller, the internals which are irrelevant to them are hidden away. It is really the very same thing as asking what is the difference between a private variable with setters/getters or a public variable in a C++ class. Indeed opaque type implementations as demonstrated on Wikipedia are preferred: they also remove the multi-threading issue. But suggesting that to the OP might be straying a tad bit too far away from the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have static in .h file defined and including that `.h` file in `.c` files you are basically defining static variable in each .c file and they are all different objects.

You have to do

```
extern short mode;
```

in some `.h` file and include this `.h` in whichever `.c` file you need.

Once the variable is declared in some `.h` file you need to define it somewhere.. I mean in some `.c` file.

```
short mode;
```

Comment: And you have to say `short mode;` in one of the c files.

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable declaration to `file1.c` and get rid of `static`:

```
  short mode=0;
```

Add an `extern` definition to `file1.h`:

```
  extern short mode;
```

Comment: No, don't add spaghetti to a properly designed program! Write setter/getter functions.

Comment: @Lundin And C is, frankly, the wrong language for that approach.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Good program design is, frankly, completely unrelated to which programming language you are using. Programming in C is certainly not an excuse for writing crap code!

Comment: @Lundin Bad code comes in many forms - overengineering is one of them. It's best to use programming techniques that are appropriate for the situation.

Comment: @JackWhitham There is an overwhelming amount of research and widely-recognized coding standards that all say that global variables are bad. Regardless of programming language. There exists very few if any cases where (non const) global variables are the correct solution to a problem. Even if they seem to be because the use is limited and the code is simple, further development/maintenance of that code which seemed simple at first, may add complexity and need for even more variables. And if you used global variables in the original code, then that is the moment when bad code rot begins.

Comment: I advocate only *appropriate* use of techniques. Coding standards can enforce bad design as easily as they can enforce good design. The overhead of the set/get paradigm is not normally the extra clock cycles, but rather the extra lines you had to add to the source files and the extra time the maintenance programmer spends reading them in order to understand what's happening. In some cases this is for the best, in other cases it is not. If you blindly stick to "XYZ considered harmful" no matter what, then you end up doing other harmful things instead.

Comment: @Lundin Also, we are discussing very fundamental properties of the programming language here. Getters and setters must be backed by a store, some variable. Possibly global, or maybe file or function static. A thorough understanding of the programming language facilities is the first and fundamental prerequisite for *any* programming in this language.

Answer (score -1):

That is the semantics of `static` in this context: It creates a separate variable in each source file.

For a common variable which spans several source files you need `extern` declarations in each source file which wants to use it -- typically through a header --, and *one*  definition in one of the source files.

On a general note, I can recommend the C FAQ (http://c-faq.com/). There is a section about declarations and definitions, http://c-faq.com/decl/decldef.html.